# Erlang receive is not receiving

Tags: erlang

I Have a storage actor that should get new data from collector actor every second. But for some reason the loop is not collecting. Its like the loop is not working at all.

```
start(Server)->
  spawn(storage,init,[Server]).

init(Server)->
  Pid = getWeather:start(self()),
  loop(#hourlyHistory{measurements=[]},#cityHistory{measurements = []},Server, Pid).

loop(Hourly = #hourlyHistory{measurements = Hh}, City = #cityHistory{measurements = Ch}, Server, Collector)->
  receive
    {hourly, {Time, Data}} ->
      Measurement = #data{timestamp = Time, data = Data},
      case addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(Measurement, Hh) of
        {H1, ok} ->
          Server ! 'new hourly',
          loop(Hourly#hourlyHistory{measurements=H1},City,Server,Collector);
        {H1, nok} -> loop(Hourly#hourlyHistory{measurements=H1},City,Server,Collector);
        _ -> loop(Hourly,City,Server,Collector)
      end
end

addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, []) -> {[New], ok};
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [New]) -> {[New], nok};
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [Old]) -> {[New | Old], ok};
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New ,[New|T]) -> {[New| T], nok};
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [Old|T]) -> {[New, Old | T], ok}.
```

This is the data collector I know that the sender is working and sending after each second, but the storage is not receiving anything.

```
start(Collector)->
  H = spawn(getWeather, senderHourly, [Collector]),
  C = spawn(getWeather, senderCity, [Collector]),
  loop(H,C).

loop(H,C)->
  receive
    close ->
      H ! close,
      C ! close
  end.

senderHourly(Collector)->
  Collector ! {hourly, getHourlyForecast()},
  receive
    close -> io:format("Closing hourly checker")
  after 1000 -> senderHourly(Collector)
  end.
```

What might be the issue here ?

Edit

```
getHourlyForecast()->
  inets:start(),
  {ok,{_Status,_Header, Body}} = httpc:request(?HOURLY_URL),
  {Xml, _Rest} = xmerl_scan:string(Body),
  template(Xml).

template(E = #xmlElement{name='observations'})->
  { xmerl_xs:xslapply(fun template/1, xmerl_xs:select("@timestamp",E)),xmerl_xs:xslapply(fun template/1, E)};
template(E = #xmlElement{name='station'})->
  ["Jaam: " , xmerl_xs:value_of(xmerl_xs:select("name",E)), " Temperature: " ,xmerl_xs:value_of(xmerl_xs:select("airtemperature",E))];
template(E) -> xmerl_xs:built_in_rules(fun template/1, E).
```

SOLVED

getWeather:start(self()) goes into loop whiodut spawning a procces for the loop, so it gets stuck there. if in getWeather start i spawn a procces for the loop it got fixed

```
start(Collector)->
  spawn(getWeather,init,[Collector]).

init(Collector)->
  H = spawn(getWeather, senderHourly, [Collector]),
  C = spawn(getWeather, senderCity, [Collector]),
  loop(H,C).
```

Comment: Where is `getHourlyForecast` defined? Are you sure it returns a tuple?

Comment: @Dogbert added the function.

Comment: Are you sure it returns a tuple? I can see at least the second clause of `template/1` returns a list, which won't match your `receive`.

Comment: @Dogbert location of data http://www.ilmateenistus.ee/ilma_andmed/xml/observations.php And when i call getHourlyForecast manually i always can match it to  tuple

Comment: Can you try adding a catch-all clause to the `receive` to see if the process is receiving messages that don't match the pattern? Add this after the `{hourly, {Time, Data}}` clause: `X -> io:format("received unknown message: ~p~n", [X])`.

Comment: @Dogbert i found the problem. It got stuck in a loop that was run on the same process.