# For each throws error in erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to send all of the list content over TCP but i get some error

Code that send the list data

```
sendHistory(To, List) ->
  lists:foreach(fun(#data{timestamp = T, data = D})->
    gen_tcp:send(To, T),
    gen_tcp:send(To, D)
                end, List).
```

And I get this error.

```
Error in process <0.65.0> with exit value:
{function_clause,[{lists,foreach,
                         [#Fun<storage.0.129058542>,
                          {data,["1495971980"],
                                ["\n\t",
                             ["Jaam: ",
                              ["Kuressaare linn"],
                              " Temperature: ",[]],
                             "\n\t",...]}],
                         [{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1337}]},
                  {storage,loop,4,[{file,"storage.erl"},{line,61}]}]}
```

Comment: From the error message it looks like `List` is a tuple `{data, ...}`, not a list.

Comment: @Dogbert could i be that my method where i check if element is already in list causes this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218559/erlang-receive-is-not-receiving?noredirect=1#comment75448190_44218559 look at the method loop and addToListIfNotAlreadyIn

Comment: Looks like you're passing a `data` record instead of one of its fields. Did you mean to extract the `data` _field_ of the `data` record and pass that to `lists:foreach`?

Comment: @Dogbert No its a list of data records. The error sees to come at the last element of the list. All the other elements are sent  fine, but the last element gives error.

Comment: Ah, wild guess, but can you try changing this clause: `{[New | Old], ok};` to `{[New, Old], ok};` in `addToListIfNotAlreadyIn/2`?

Comment: How was build the list? It may be an improper list of the form `[A,B,C|D]` where D is not a list. It often occurs when you start to build a list, but forget to put the first element in a list: first step prepend C to D doing `[C|D]` rather than `[C|[D]]`.

Comment: Yeah I think the clause I mentioned above is creating an improper list. The error message is identical to what I get for passing improper lists to `lists:foreach/2`.

Comment: Yup that solved it. I changed my list thingy  it now is like this
  `addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, []) -> {[New|[]], ok};
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New ,[New|T]) -> {[New| T], nok};
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [Old|T]) -> {[New, Old | T], ok}.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line clause in your previous code is creating an improper list:

```
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [Old]) -> {[New | Old], ok};
```

You probably meant to write:

```
addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [Old]) -> {[New, Old], ok};
```

The error message means that `lists:foreach/2` was called with a second argument which was not a list. Since `lists:foreach/2` [recursively calls itself with the tail of the list after applying the function to the head](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/0ab4a336d0935c47b26cceb202ab63344c03b8a2/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L1337-L1340), if an improper list is passed to the function, it will end up calling itself with a non-list argument on the last iteration:

```
1> lists:foreach(fun(X) -> ok end, [1, 2, 3 | 4]).
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:foreach(#Fun<erl_eval.6.118419387>,4) (lists.erl, line 1337)
```

Comment: The best thing to do is to remove the clause `addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [Old]) -> {[New | Old], ok};` since it is already part of the last clause of the function: the whole function can be written with only the clauses number 1,4 and 5, the number 2 `addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New, [New]) -> {[New], nok};`( and 3) is a particular case of number 4 `addToListIfNotAlreadyIn(New ,[New|T]) -> {[New| T], nok};` (and 5) where `T = []`